# index.js not uploading to github, keeps getting ignored

Tags: reactjs, git, github, create-react-app

created a new project by using npx create-react-app newproject. Index.js inside /src keeps getting ignored when trying to upload it to github. Everything gets uploaded correctly. Is this a problem with webpack, any dependencies? This is unusual.

folders and such:

[image]

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

.gitignore:

```
node_modules
build
```

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.4.5"
  }
}
```

Uploading process:  git add . && git commit -m "commit message here" && git push origin main

Comment: you should uninitialize the git repo, delete the .gitignore file, reload the editor then again initialize it as a git repo and create a .gitignore file again.

Comment: Dont drop your repo yet. Try `git add -f src/index.js` to force add the file

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal tried again with a new project, without git init, run npx create-react-app, problem still occurs.

Comment: @epicmau5time tried your solution, it does work but there has to be a better one for present and future projects :/

Comment: It seems just to be with your folder itself. It should not happen with brand new projects.

Comment: @epicmau5time I tried again, same steps, keeps happening.

Comment: Please edit your post with the exact process of how you are uploading your changes to GitHub.

Comment: @riQQ git add . && git commit -m "commit message here" && git push origin main